# How to replace inner html onClick on each loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to loop each thru of the attribute and if it matches,  it will replace the inner HTML of the DOM. For this example, I'm trying to replace the data-product="momentum-shorts-2-0" inner HTML DOM which is the `<h2>Momentum Shorts 2.0 NEW</h2>` contents into the `<div> class="compare-main" </div>` that I've highlighted in the screenshot..

This is what I have with my code now but i'm stuck.. it keeps returning to me singular value of the last item..

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        
        $( ".compare-filter-item" ).click(function() {
            var selected_data_product = $(this).attr("data-product");
       
            
            $(".compare-all .compare-products [data-product='" + selected_data_product + "']").each(function(){
              
                new_html = $(this).html();
                $(".compare-main .compare-products [data-product='" + selected_data_product + "']").each(function(){
                    $(this).html(new_html);
                })
            });
             
        });

    })
</script>
```

[image]

Issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        
        $( ".compare-filter-item" ).click(function() {
            var selected_data_product = "momentum-shorts-2-0";
       
            $(".compare-main .compare-products [data-product='" + selected_data_product + "']").each(function(){
                $(this).find("h2").text("Momentum Shorts 2.0");
            });
             
        });

    })
</script>
```

I tried to understand your requirement and here is the solution see if it help.

Comment: My intention is to replace the inner DOM HTML. Im trying to pull the INNER DOM HTML from the  "compare-all" wrapper to the "compare-main" wrapper elements by matching the data-product if they are selected from the dropdown.. im sorry im not explaining well...